# Is a degree from an overseas institution likely to be a barrier to employment with a major US airline?

Tags: usa, airline-pilot, career

I'm currently enrolled at a university in Jamaica. However, on my school break I often come to the US for flight training. I would like to know if a major US airline would employ me after completing my degree, given that it is an overseas degree?

Comment: It isn't clear what type of job you are after. Are you wanting a pilots position? Are you training for your commercial/ATP? What type of operation do you want to work for? Corporate? Airline? Cargo? What degree are you pursuing?

Comment: I think that this question is really in regards to the commonly cited requirement of a four year college degree that the "Major" airlines will look for in a candidate, regardless of the other requirements such as certifications and logged time. In other words, does an "overseas degree" count?

Comment: I just started my privite license training.and yes i am working towards becoming  atp pilot.I have an associate degree in industrial engineering.an currently pursuing a degree in finance.

Comment: I often hear airlines emphasize on 4 year degree.thou i have no interest in working in finance department..I'm just pursuing a degree becasue its a requirement of most major US airlines.i was just curious if after I clock my hours and have all my ratings.if major airlines would "look down"onmy degree giving that I didn't attend a local institution

Comment: It is unlikely that you would be "looked down on" if you are otherwise qualified, however it is certainly possible that an airline would prefer to have an individual with an aviation related degree.

Answer (score 4):

Without a considerable amount of time as PIC of a turbine-powered aircraft, I expect your chances would be slight.

Once your other qualifications, logbook, and resume are competitive, I doubt that where you went to college will matter very much.